# Combine Identifier pattern with `as` pattern

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

How can I copy the result of the Identifier pattern to an as pattern to make a tuple?

My question is confused, so I created an example, I want to print the information of the person, who is either a teacher or a student:

```
type Person =
    | Teacher of name: string * age: int * classIds: int list
    | Student of name: string

let printTeacher (name, age, classIds) =
    printfn "Teacher: %s; Age: %d; Classes: %A" name age classIds

let print = function
    | Teacher (name, age, classIds) -> printTeacher (name, age, classIds)
    | Student name -> printfn "Student: %s" name
```

The matching pattern is long and repetitive:

```
| Teacher (name, age, classIds) -> printTeacher (name, age, classIds)
```

So I tried to make it shorter using the `as` pattern, but failed:

```
| Teacher ((_, _, _) as teacher) -> printTeacher teacher
```

Because the above `teacher` has the `Person` type, and not `string*int*int list`. What should I do to have a shorter pattern, without changing the `printTeacher` type signature `string*int*int list -> unit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is by changing the definition of the `Teacher` constructor:

```
type Person =
    | Teacher of items: (string * int * int list)
    | Student of name: string

let printTeacher (name, age, classIds) =
    printfn "Teacher: %s; Age: %d; Classes: %A" name age classIds

let print = function
    //| Teacher (name, age, classIds) -> printTeacher (name, age, classIds) // Still works
    | Teacher items -> printTeacher items
    | Student name -> printfn "Student: %s" name
```

By changing the `Teacher` to take an explicit tuple, you can reference it by name, but the other way still works as well.

You lose the functionality to give names to your tuple items, though.

If you do not want to or cannot change your type definition, another way is to introduce an active pattern for the Teacher constructor:

```
type Person =
    | Teacher of name: string * age: int * classIds: int list
    | Student of name: string

// Active pattern to extract Teacher constructor into a 3-tuple.
let (|TeacherTuple|_|) = function
| Teacher (name, age, classIds) -> Some (name, age, classIds)
| _ -> None

let printTeacher (name, age, classIds) =
    printfn "Teacher: %s; Age: %d; Classes: %A" name age classIds

let print = function
    | TeacherTuple items -> printTeacher items
    | Student name -> printfn "Student: %s" name
    // To make the compiler happy. It doesn't know that the pattern matches all Teachers.
    | _ -> failwith "Unreachable."
```